# Installing software center ubuntu

Tags: software-center

Okay so I recently had some problems with ubuntu software centre where if I opened it from the dashboard it would open up, but only display a white screen. Nothing happened, so if I then clicked the 'x', it would ask me if i would like to force close the non responding software centre.

To get round this I've been opening the software centre via terminal which seems to let it work fine.

But i needed it working normally and after lots of attempts I couldn't figure it out so decided to just un-install and reinstall it.

Un-install worked fine, but now for the reinstall. When i type into terminal

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

I get this back;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

any ideas? Thanks :)

Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get install software-center*` (with an asterisk) and see if that gives you any ideas?

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get update`. Your apt cache seems broken, and apt cannot find the package. Running the update command should resolve it, or at least give you more information about whey it's broken.

Comment: **1111** Great.. :D

Answer (score 30):

You need to type

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

to install software center.

Answer (score 17):

Like @dobey said, you should give the command `sudo apt-get update` a whirl. You may have a problem with your apt-cache and as such, you *will* have problems installing things.

Run the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. This will check for any and all updates/upgrades, hopefully fixing your system.

Once this runs, try running @sebastian_k's answer, `sudo apt-get install software-center*`. This will get/install anything and everything that Ubuntu Software Center needs to run.

Comment: Already tried the;
    sudo apt-get update

and the software-center* has no luck :/

Comment: Oh, hmm. Dunno then...I'll keep looking though. Hope you find the answer soon, having a broken system is not fun (I've had to reinstall a few times because of it.)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but in the end ive just resorted to completely wiping my hard drive and installing ubuntu 13.04. Always nice to have a fresh start every now and then!

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the repository link.
From:
Main Menu: System > Administration > Software Sources.
Make sure that the Main repository is selected.
You can get a PPA with:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:software-store-developers/daily-build
or
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuone/nightlies

It's generally recommended to just download the source code

You can get it from:

https://launchpad.net/software-center

Or directly from:

https://launchpad.net/software-center/stable-13-10/13.08/+download/software-center-13.08.tar.gz

Or you can get it in Synaptic.

Comment: I don't believe he need a ppa to install USC.